# Store integer from GET (Numbers Comparison)

Tags: php

Scenario is as follows (Sorry in advance for my lack of knowledge - this has me at my wits end and have no other solution before I post here )

$_GET['id'] has a value of 216 I then Store the value 216 in $idcheck

if $_GET['id'] (is changed in the URL to ?id=217)
and the page is resubmitted ,I then want to check/validate
that $idcheck value 216 is equal or not equal to $_GET['id'] value 217

EXAMPLE

```
if ($idcheck != $_GET['id'])  {
/// do somthing
}else{
/// do somthing
}
```

EXAMPLE

```
echo $_GET['id'];

$_SESSION['idcheck'] = "216";

if($_GET['id'] == $_SESSION['idcheck']  )  {

echo "it matches";

}else{

echo "Sorry You cannot do that ";
die();
}
```

How can I achieve this as every-time the page reloads $idcheck gets the same value
as $_GET['id'] therefore my if condition will always be true.

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to achieve. In order to compare the value with the session, you, obviously, have to `startSession()` and then save the value to it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, then you need to check the `current id` with the `previous id` got from URL query param.

In the below code, we first check whether the SESSION variable for id is set or not. If set then we also check is that is matches the current id. `If both evaluates true then There is a Match.`

`If any of the condition fails, then no match found.`

```php
<?php

if ( isset($_SESSION['last_id']) &&  ($_SESSION['last_id'] == $_GET['id']) ) {
    // Matches
}
else {
    // No Match
}
$_SESSION['last_id'] = $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: This works however it does it backwards -  it allows me to view other pages and not the one I should .

Comment: I can view other pages example:acceptmember.php?id=214 or 212 , 210 however when I go to :acceptmember.php?id=216  I cannot view this (this is the page I land on that does the check first) IT appear the code is doing the check backwards.

Comment: Actually, acceptmember.php is a single file and you can load different data based on the Query Param `id`. 

But I am still not sure what you requirement is. what I post in answer is only I can infer from your question.

Comment: And I can't understand what you mean by `I can View`.

Comment: Sorry by View, I mean . I can access (load) the data from the page which is done using the ID from the database , So I should only be allowed access the ID that is permitted therefore anything else should not be authorized

Comment: Then you can simply Check the `id from URL is available and valid in the DB by Querying Database' and Show the Intended result if found or show  a 403 Permission Denied Page.

Comment: I need to check the id in the URL and not the DB , Thanks .

Comment: So, you have complete logic or data of which ID's should be permitted and which IDs should not ?
Are these seperation defined ?

Comment: I could have used a $_SESSION to store the id instead of using it in the URL however I couldn't due to the nature of the code which is sending a message to a user in their inbox - they then click this message as it sends them to another users profile where the id is in the link to the url - The way the code is structured I need to check the URL and validate it from that .

Comment: Let's say you have complete and clear separation over which ID should be permitted and which are not. For example, when the id from URL is 216 then show the content else show 'You are not permitted' message. Then you can simply check the id is equal to 216 and show the content. If not change the page content to message. A simple if condition is enough for this requirement.

Comment: Can you explain the requirement in Top View. Like User got message in inbox. They click and the link redirects to another user profile. Then what should it check ?

Comment: Also from your last sentence in the question `How can I achieve this as every-time the page reloads $idcheck gets the same value as $_GET['id'] therefore my if condition will always be true.`. You are storing the URL Query Param `id` in `$idcheck`. So when you change the URL, let''s say `script.php?id=216` to `script.php?id=219` then the $_GET['id'] will result in 219. And remember the `$idcheck` variable is got changes since you have refreshed the page. If you want to preserve a variable you have to use $_SESSION or $_COOKIE etc.

Comment: Any user can get an invitation (friend-request) which contains the id in the URL therefore I cannot control each id per say for each user , only thing i can do is check that the invitation id in the link matches the id in the URL .  I really appreciate your input and insight .

Comment: I have used $_SESSION['idcheck']  but it does not store(hold) the idnumber I want to check against I refresh the page and $_SESSION['idcheck']  is the same value as $_GET

Comment: `Invitation ID in the Friend Request Link will be the value always in the URL`. The URL and Link are same. If you click on a Link then That is what the browser request for. For example, if you click on `stackoverflow.com/id=3` then $_GET['id'] will be 3.

Comment: I have idea based on your recommendation of a simple if statement , I can store the id in the  invitation request in a table then do a check to see if the URL id matches - if it does then run the accept invitation code else exit , this will stop users from changing the id in the url and getting an unauthorized invitation - Once the id matches i can just run a DELETE from to remove the id from the table . Thanks for making think , i know its one of many ways to solve but i will try this .

Comment: As you said create an entry in the DB with a column status default to (0 or false) once the link is shareable. Once someone visits with the shared id then change the status of the corresponding record to 1 or true. You don't need to delete the entry from the table. The data can be useful in future.

Comment: Yes this way has worked - Thanks once more for helping me think better